# Brezis Proposition 9.3 Remark 7

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I have a question about remark 7 which is written after Propostion 9.3 in Brezis Functional Analysis book. It states in particular that if $f\in W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$, then there exists $C>0$ for every $K \subset \Omega$ that is compact, for all $h\in \mathbb R^n$ such as $|h|<\text{dist}(K,\partial\Omega)$ we have 
$$\Vert\tau_hf-f\Vert_{L^\infty(K)}\le \| \nabla f\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)} |h|$$
where $\tau_hf(x)=f(x+h)$.

Remark 7 states that this proposition implies that every $f\in W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$ has a continuous representative.

Can somebody explain me how to obtain the last statement by using only propostion 9.3 if it is possible?

In fact, the proposition implies that for every $K \subset \Omega$ that is compact, for every $h\in \mathbb R^n$ such as $|h|<\text{dist}(K,\partial\Omega)$ and for ALMOST EVERY $x \in K$ we have
$$|f(x-h)-f(x)| \leq |h| \| \nabla f\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)}$$

And that seems to be not enough to prove that $f$ has a continuous representative, because it is not correct to say that for almost every $x \in K$ and for every $h\in \mathbb R^n$ such as $|h|<\text{dist}(K,\partial\Omega)$ we have
$$|f(x-h)-f(x)| \leq |h| \| \nabla f\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)}$$

I have also remarked that if we prove that $f$ is continuous almost everywhere, it is easy to deduce that $f$ has a continuous representative. However, I haven't managed to prove that $f$ is continuous almost everywhere.

Feel free to give some hints in the comments, to give some advice or to ask some intermediate questions. Any comment is welcome!

Comment: Take the representative to be $f^*(x):= lim_{r\to 0^+} \frac{1}{|B(x,r)|}\int_{B(x,r)} f(y)\,dy$.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I guess I have found a solution for my problem.

Let $K \subset \Omega$ a compact subset and $\delta = \text{dist}(K,\partial\Omega)$. For $0 < \epsilon < \delta$, we may define on $K$ the function $g_{\epsilon} (x) = \frac{1}{|B(0,\epsilon)|}\int_{B(0,\epsilon)} f(x+h)\,dh $

Comment: Then we can prove that $g_{\epsilon}$ converges to $f$ in $L^{\infty} (K)$ when $\epsilon$ converges to $0$.

Comment: Then we can prove that $g_{\epsilon}$ is continuous on $K$.

Comment: Both of the last facts can be proved as a direct application of the proposition 9.3

Comment: Yes, that exactly right!